# Application User with virtual 1-1 child

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have extended `ApplicationUser` class within the framework supplied `IndentityModel` to include profile information (called Expert)

```
namespace learn4.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {   
            // so a new Profile is created at the time of registeration
            if (expert == null) expert = new Expert();

        }
        public virtual Expert expert { get; set; }
    }
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Expert> Experts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Expert is defined as below

```
public class Expert
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; } //
    public string FirstName { get; set; } //
    public string LastName { get; set; } //
    public string MiddleNames { get; set; } //
    public DateTime? DateofBirth { get; set; } //
}
```

I expect,

1. on new registration Expert is null and a new record is created.
2. On login ApplicationUser.Expert is not null anymore and will retrieve the expert record created in step 1

1 is working as expected, see data screenshots
[image]

2 is not working as expected, i.e. at login, I always have a null expert and my logic now creates a new instance as below (debug screenshot)

[image]

what am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Your question is about ASP.NET MVC implementation, not about the mvc architecture, so it shouldn't be in [model-view-controller] tag. Refer this from the [model-view-controller] tag description: `For Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, please use [asp.net-mvc] tag instead.`.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, there's zero point in having `Expert` in the first place. The whole point of Identity was to allow you customized things like the "User" in any way you see fit. Therefore, the correct way to add additional "profile" information is *right on the user object*:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } //
    public string LastName { get; set; } //
    public string MiddleNames { get; set; } //
    public DateTime? DateofBirth { get; set; } //
}
```

Second, you're not creating a 1-to-1 here, but rather a 1-to-many. To create a 1-to-1, you would need the following on your `Expert` class:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

That should be enough for Entity Framework to guess that you're defining a 1-to-1, but I always like to be specific about my intentions:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasRequired(m => m.Expert)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(m => m.User);
}
```

Comment: +1 and thanks Chris / but I will stick to storing the information in a different as advised in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx do you see where i deviated from what is advised here?

Comment: The linked article does not advise that you store profile information in a different table; it merely presents it as an option. The first set of code there shows you how to add info directly on the user class. While you can technically go either way, using a separate table incurs overhead as you have to constantly do a join anytime you want a complete picture of the user. The best way to go is to keep everything on one table.